# Issue creating many server's from one class Corba

Tags: java, corba

For a uni assignment, we have to create a way of managing flood sensors and alerting once if the water level becomes to high. So my idea was to create a LMS (Local Monitoring Station) which would hold an arrayList of sensor Servers and then manage them from there.

So I created a test class to test the implementation of adding them;

```
public class testClass 
{
    static public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<FloodSensorServer> sensors = new ArrayList<FloodSensorServer>();

        sensors.add(new FloodSensorServer("Sensor 1"));
        sensors.add(new FloodSensorServer("Sensor 2"));
        sensors.add(new FloodSensorServer("Sensor 3"));
        sensors.add(new FloodSensorServer("Sensor 4"));

    }
}
```

Logically, I thought this might have worked, Till I ran it and saw that it ran the first .add and then stopped. I then realized it was stopping because of this line of code;

```
orb.run();  


public class FloorSensorServer 
{
Sensor counter;
String sensorName;

public FloorSensorServer(String sensorName)
{
    this.sensorName = sensorName;
    createServer();
}

public void createServer()
{
    try {
        // Initialize the ORB
        System.out.println("Creating sensor: " + sensorName);

        String[] newArgs = {"-ORBInitialPort", "1050"}; 
        ORB orb = ORB.init(newArgs, null);

        // get reference to rootpoa & activate the POAManager
        POA rootpoa = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
        rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

        // Create the Count servant object
        FloorSensorImpl sensor = new FloorSensorImpl(sensorName);

        // get object reference from the servant
        org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootpoa.servant_to_reference(sensor);
        Sensor cref = SensorHelper.narrow(ref);

        // Get a reference to the Naming service
        org.omg.CORBA.Object nameServiceObj = 
                orb.resolve_initial_references ("NameService");
        if (nameServiceObj == null) {
            System.out.println("nameServiceObj = null");
            return;
        }

        // Use NamingContextExt which is part of the Interoperable
        // Naming Service (INS) specification.
        NamingContextExt nameService = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(nameServiceObj);
        if (nameService == null) {
            System.out.println("nameService = null");
            return;
        }

        NameComponent[] countName = nameService.to_name(sensorName);
        nameService.rebind(countName, cref);

        //  wait for invocations from clients
        orb.run();            

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How would one deal with a situation like this? Or am I going about this the totally wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You have the same ORB initial port for all of them. To create multiple CORBA servers you must give each of them its own port...

That is, in

```
String[] newArgs = {"-ORBInitialPort", "1050"};
```

the port `"1050"` cannot be a magical constant but needs to be a parameter or a local variable which is changed to a new value for each created server.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that at all, guess throwing stuff together and hoping it works is not really the best approach to this, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: That is a fairly common way of doing things. I do it all the time :D but you have to be prepared to face the consequences as well - and never show it to any one in a management position until you've cleaned it up :p

Comment: Wait, either I'm understanding this wrong or I'm just confused. Doesn't that port simply define where the namingService is located? As the second you change the port it errors as it cannot find the nameServer at the new port defined. @fredrik

Comment: each sersor has it's own namingService, as you've set it up now. And you can only have one namingService per port. Of course it is possible that I've misinterpreted what you have there - but given from what I currently know about your code and CORBA, the initial port cannot be the same for two servers.

Comment: I think we're both confused. The nameSpace is a separate .exe run before the server. 

`/c tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1050` 

So when creating the server it looks for this namespace and then assigns the servant object and it's name onto the space, which a client can then access and use, I think. @fredrik

Comment: Ahh, then whay you have should work. But to make it simpler I would only do this binding once, then only create and assign new `FloorSensorImpl` instances to the existing binding...